# Play 2.3: RESTful API, Invalid Json Html

Tags: java, json, rest, playframework-2.0, body-parser

Why does Play want to give an html error page for sending a request that doesn't have valid json, rather than allowing the controller to have the action method handle it?  I'm trying to write a RESTful service that returns a Json response, and this problem is a blocker.

I've tried using the provided BodyParser annotation: BodyParser.TolerantJson.class

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.TolerantJson.class, maxLength = 2 * 1024)
```

That is supposed to ignore what's sent in the header for the content type and allow to process it in the action method, but doesn't appear to.  Is this a bug?  I can set the header content type to text and it will allow invalid json (I can , but I don't want to have customers do this, and I don't want to ignore the json header, as it should be sent.

The response I'm getting is an html page with the text:

```
For request 'POST /api/v1/create' [Invalid Json]
```

And in case it's helpful, here's the Java code:

```
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.TolerantJson.class, maxLength = 2 * 1024) //2KB
public static Result create() {

    //none of this code executes when the header is json
    PojoApiResponse response;

    JsonNode body = request().body().asJson();

    response = XternalPartnerApiService.create(body);

    JsonNode ret = Json.toJson(response);

    if(response.getHttpStatus() == Http.Status.BAD_REQUEST){
        return badRequest(ret);
    } else {
        return ok(ret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define onBadRequest in Global

src:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal